# Hibernate - Could not determine type for columns: org.hibernate.mapping.Column(binding)

Tags: git, hibernate, groovy, hibernate-mapping

My Hibernate-based Grails app is unable to build every time after I pull code from Git and fails on Hibernate mapping. The problem is, it works on my friend's system and I have no idea why it crashes on mine. There's been many similar posts regarding this exception and they mainly related to problems within columns. The difference here is that there is no such column as "binding" in my table. Here's the exception code:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: groovy.lang.Binding, at table: business_process, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(binding)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:454)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:595)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:464)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:711)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.java:241)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.doBuildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.java:474)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.java:468)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

This is my Domain class that defines the table:

```
class ScBusinessProcess {

    String name;

    ScStep step;

    String description;

    boolean promoted;

    static hasMany = [
            likes: ScBusinessProcessLike,
            questions: ScQuestion
    ]

    static constraints = {
        step nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'BUSINESS_PROCESS'
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try command 'grails clean' before running the application. It worked for me.

Purpose:
The clean command deletes all compiled resources from the application. Since Groovy is a compiled language, as with Java, this is sometimes useful to clear old instances of classes and ensure correct compilation. It's also a good idea to run this script before running tests or creating a WAR file to ensure a full compilation occurs.

reference: http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Command%20Line/clean.html